# Keep getting 500 Internal Server Error when using Passenger

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, redmine, 500-error

Every time I restart my server, which is a MediaTemple VPS, our Redmine installation, which is powered by Passenger through Apache, starts giving out 500 Internal Server Errors. It usually starts working again when I restart Apache, but it's become very annoying. Could I get some help with this?

Here's what the Apache error log has to say:

```
/usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.4/helper-scripts/passenger-spawnserver:75:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError) from /usr/local/rubygems/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.4/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:75
[ pid=6133 thr=3079579408 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:864 time=2011-03-26 16:43:57.147 ]: Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot spawn application '…/redmine': Could not read from the spawn server: Connection reset by peer (104)
  Backtrace:
     in 'virtual Passenger::SessionPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool::Client::get(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (Client.h:750)
     in 'Passenger::SessionPtr Hooks::getSession(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (Hooks.cpp:297)
     in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:566)
```